I can't get my sam local start-api to work with Typescript
I can't for the life of me understand how I would set up SAM to run my Typescript/nodejs api locally.
I run sam local start-api and everything kind of starts up. Lots and lots of debug logging that doesn't tell me anything. Once I try to invoke the API endpoint with CURL I get the following error message:
26 Apr 2024 00:43:22,108 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=
26 Apr 2024 00:43:22,109 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=3506a416-5cd1-42a3-ba56-45ffa76d2369
26 Apr 2024 00:43:22,110 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke DONE failed: Sandbox.Failure

Here's an example of how I set up a lambda function in the SAM template yaml:
  GetAuthenticatedUserDetailsFunction:
      CodeUri: ../
      Handler: GetAuthenticatedUserDetails.lambdaHandler
      Events:
        GetAuthenticatedUserDetails:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref api
            Path: /gaud
            Method: get
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17' 
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: "rds-db:connect"
              Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:rds-db:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:dbuser:${DBProxyPRXID}/*'
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
        - src/GetAuthenticatedUserDetails.ts

What am I doing wrong? I thought the sam cli would be smart enough to figure all this out by itself?
Here are some things that I already know

Entrypoints attribute contains the "src" directory. If I move that dir to the CodeUri attribute then sam build fails by saying that esbuild doesn't exist on my machine (but magically does exist with this config)
The sam build command transpiles all the .ts code to .js dirs in the ./aws-sam directory. But! It has a different structure where the code is compiled per function.

I understand that the error points to the fact that sam local can't find the function in whatever directory it is looking in. The Typescript code is transpiled into a .aws-sam/ directory that has a completely different structure (I assume it's self contained and will be zipped up for deployment).
I did try to hack the CodeUri attribute to point to the .aws-sam directory

Ok so I think just typing out the question made my brain start working.
The epiphany was that if I just run tsc src/*.ts --outputDir dist I will get the javascript versions of the Typescript files in a 'dist' directory with the exact same dir structure.
So if I just use the dist dir as the code URI everything will be found by sam local.
The solution was to create a shell script that looks like:
rm -rf ./dist
tsc ./src/*.ts --outDir ./dist
sudo sam local start-api --debug --region us-east-1 -t ./template-local.yaml 

I made two different sam templates - one for local and one for AWS. Those templates more or less just sets the codeUri and then I call the actual API template file as a nested stack.
Hopefully someone will be helped by this therapy session
